# Checking variable colors

Tags: javascript, if-statement

How can I get the following function to return multiple color types (not just red, but also orange, yellow, etc.) without using multiple if/else statements?

```
function isRainbowColor(color){
  if (color === "red"){
  return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
console.log(isRainbowColor("red"));
 //This returns true, but only for one color at a time.  How can I add onto ?
```

Comment: So you want to compare one string to multiple values?

Comment: Create an Array of colors then test for `colorsArray.includes(argument)`.

Answer (score 2):

Create an array of acceptable colors, and check the `color` with the `Array.includes()` function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

```js
function isRainbowColor(color){
  let acceptableColors = ["red","orange","yellow","blue","green"]
  if (acceptableColors.includes(color)){
  return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
console.log(isRainbowColor("red"));
console.log(isRainbowColor("green"));
console.log(isRainbowColor("purple"));
 //This returns true, but only for one color at a time.  How can I add onto ?
```

Comment: how about just `return acceptableColors.includes(color)` ??

Comment: @RandyCasburn I thought about changing it to that, but I didn't want to change up their code too much and possibly confuse them.

Comment: Yeah - I upvoted you anyway. The `if` statement simply serves no purpose, but I understand about confusing them.

Comment: Side note: you'd probably want `acceptableColors` to be `const` here